# Jackson infinite recursion working with a query

Tags: java, json, jpa, recursion, jackson

I have this JPA method which fetches a list of "to do" between 2 dates from the database using a query.

```
public List<Tarea> findTareasEntreFechas(Long idUsuario, Date fechaInicio, Date fechaFin) {
    return jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
        TypedQuery<Tarea> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT t " 
                + "FROM Tarea t "
                + "WHERE usuario.id = :userId "
                + "AND t.hecha is FALSE "
                + "AND t.fechaFinalizacion >= :fechaInicio "
                + "AND t.fechaFinalizacion <= :fechaFin "
        , Tarea.class);
        try {
            List<Tarea> tareas = query.setParameter("userId", idUsuario)
                .setParameter("fechaInicio", fechaInicio)
                .setParameter("fechaFin", fechaFin)
                .getResultList();
            return tareas;
        }
        catch(NoResultException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my Tarea entity.

```
package models;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Tarea {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String titulo;
    // Relación muchos-a-uno entre tareas y usuario
    @ManyToOne
    // Nombre de la columna en la BD que guarda físicamente
    // el ID del usuario con el que está asociado una tarea
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuarioId")
    public Usuario usuario;

    private Boolean hecha;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaFinalizacion;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tareaPadreId")
    private Tarea tareaPadre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tareaPadre", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Set<Tarea> subtareas = new HashSet<Tarea>();

    public Tarea() {
        this.hecha = false;
    }

    public Tarea(Usuario usuario, String titulo) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.hecha = false;
        this.fechaCreacion = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    public Tarea(Usuario usuario, String titulo, Date fechaFinalizacion) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.hecha = false;
        this.fechaCreacion = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        this.fechaFinalizacion = fechaFinalizacion;
    }

    // Getters y setters necesarios para JPA

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public Boolean getHecha() { return hecha; }

    public void setHecha(Boolean hecha) { this.hecha = hecha; }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getFechaFinalizacion() {
        return fechaFinalizacion;
    }

    public String getFechaFinalizacionFormateada() {
        Date fechaFinalizacion = getFechaFinalizacion();
        if(fechaFinalizacion != null) {
            return (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")).format(fechaFinalizacion);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void setFechaFinalizacion(Date fechaFinalizacion) {
        this.fechaFinalizacion = fechaFinalizacion;
    }

    public boolean isRetrasada() {
        if(fechaFinalizacion != null) {
            Date ahora = new Date();
            return ahora.after(fechaFinalizacion);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Tarea id: %s titulo: %s usuario: %s hecha: %s", id, titulo, usuario.toString(), hecha ? "si" : "no");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = prime + ((titulo == null) ? 0 : titulo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Tarea other = (Tarea) obj;
        // Si tenemos los ID, comparamos por ID
        if (id != null && other.id != null)
            return ((long) id == (long) other.id);
            // sino comparamos por campos obligatorios
        else {
            if (titulo == null) {
                if (other.titulo != null) return false;
            } else if (!titulo.equals(other.titulo)) return false;
            if (usuario == null) {
                if (other.usuario != null) return false;
                else if (!usuario.equals(other.usuario)) return false;
            }
            if (hecha == null) {
                if (other.hecha != null) return false;
                else if (!hecha.equals(other.hecha)) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Tarea getTareaPadre() {
        return tareaPadre;
    }

    public void setTareaPadre(Tarea tareaPadre) {
        this.tareaPadre = tareaPadre;
    }

    public Set<Tarea> getSubtareas() {
        return subtareas;
    }

    public void setSubtareas(Set<Tarea> subtareas) {
        this.subtareas = subtareas;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call this method from the controller and I try to serialize the returned List into JSON, It throws this exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)`

Furthermore, It doesn't happen when I manually parse the result into a String.

The point of the question is that every solution I find says that I have to put the annotation `@JsonIgnore` in one side of the relationship. I've tried that but doesn't seem to work, because the relationship itself retrieves all the "to do" of the User...

Comment: You might want to expose your `Tarea` entity.

Comment: @Mena I forgot, thanks xD

Comment: Pretty sure this has something to do with the reference to the parent entity `tareaPadre`. Have you tried to `@JsonIgnore` that?

Comment: Can you create the smallest DB table you can that demonstrates this problem, and also include that in the question?

Comment: Note : you may also want to not serialize the whole list of child entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting my comments in the form of an answer.

Your `Tarea` entity yields both references to a parent and a `Set` of children.

What happens when top entities are serialized to JSON is their children get included in the JSON.

But since the children contain a reference to their parent, their parent is serialized again too, for each child.

And as the parent also yields a reference to each child, etc. etc. etc. you can see how that would generate "infinite" JSON and produce a stack overflow.

The solution would be to ensure at least the reference to the parent is ignored (`@JsonIgnore`) when serializing, although you may also ignore the reference to children to avoid verbosity.

Speculatively digging further, if your user entity `Usuario` *also* links to task entities `Tarea`s, you may need to ignore those fields in the user as well (which you seem to have tried already, but that may not be the issue or only part of it).

Comment: I see your point, however, I've tried to ignore each one separately and both and I keep getting the same exception.

Comment: Okey, the problem was the `Usuario` relationship as you speculated. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: @JDLK7 glad it helped somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this. One is using `@JsonIgnore` as mentioned, the other is combining `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.

The first one goes in the parent class, the second in the child class. Since those classes are the same one in this instance, it might be an problem if the recursion bug is not fixed in the respective version of Jackson.

Try this (no guarantees, as I've only used it with different classes)

```
@JsonBackReference
private Tarea tareaPadre;

@JsonManagedReference
public Set<Tarea> subtareas = new HashSet<Tarea>();
```

This also helps with deserialization, as the child-objects are automatically set to point to their parent.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` as they solve the stack overflow issue while still allowing parent-child and child-parent inclusion.

Comment: Same as the first answer. I've tried that but I keep getting the same error.